# applying style to inner div on hover of outer div

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="TheOuterClass">
    <div class="TheInnerClass">some text</div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.TheOuterClass{
    width:100px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    background:black;}

.TheOuterClass:hover{
    pointer:cursor;
    background:red;
    color:yellow;}

.TheInnerClass{color:white;}
```

What I want to do is have the text of the inner div change color on hover of the outer div. How can I do this with CSS only?

The jsFiddle is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/skD7Z/)

*PS: I know it can easily be done with jQuery but this is about doing it with CSS only.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would use the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) psuedo-class on the parent element, followed by the child element.

[**Updated jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/skD7Z/1/)

```
.TheOuterClass:hover .TheInnerClass {
    color:blue;
}
```